# What is the difference between the "Android P" and "API Level 27" system images?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-api-levels, android-9.0-pie

What is the difference between the top two system images entries currently in this Android Studio dialog:
[image: Android Studio System Images]

You can see that neither **Oreo**, **API 27**, or **P** or listed in the "API level distribution chart."

[image: Android Platform/API Version Distribution]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference between the top two system images entries currently in this Android Studio dialog

Android P is the P Developer Preview, currently Developer Preview 1.

API Level 27 is [Android 8.1](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.1.html).

Answer (score 4):

[Android P](https://developer.android.com/preview/index.html) is preview 1(initial release, alpha) of the next version of Android. Whereas API 27 is the [Go Edition](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.1.html#safebrowsing) of the android Oreo(Android 8.1).

[image]
[API LEVEL DISTRIBUTION CHART](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)